# How do I get the status of many JCheckBoxMenuItems in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jmenu, jmenubar

I'm working on a program that lets me search for teachers and students through a GUI.

So you all probably know the option when searching something on a website to filter just for some information rather than everything. To achieve that, I created a `JMenuBar` and its corresponding `JMenu` with multiple `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s. If the name of a person is typed in, a method runs that checks if that person is in the system. If it is then another method is called that checks if `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s are selected or not to either proceed with conventional search or filtered search. Instead of coding every single option, I put all `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s in an `ArrayList`. I created a new method that looped through this `ArrayList` and checked if the `JCheckBoxMenItem` on position `i` `isSelected()` and if so performing a certain action, but it seems like it doesn't even loop through the whole list and just stops even though something was selected. It should technically work but I guess something is missing that I'm not seeing. If I try to execute that method it never checks if a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` is selected. I will post part of the code here and provide a link to my GitHub where you can find all the classes and the entire code : https://github.com/Gonzo-CR/Home-Projects/tree/master/project_SuchSystem

The class `TestFrame` is the GUI with the explained code. Some variables and text is written in German, I hope this won't bring any problems with it. The off placed Menubar in the GUI needs to be pressed for starting the search.

```
public void einzelLehrerSuche()
{
    model = (DefaultTableModel)table_Lehrer.getModel();
    loescheLehrerTabelle();
    String lehrername = tfSuchfeldLehrer.getText();
    boolean lehrerGefunden = false;
    if(lehrername.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < lehrerliste.size(); i++)
        {
            lehrer = lehrerliste.get(i);
            if(lehrer.getName().equals(lehrername) || lehrer.getNachname().equals(lehrername))
            {
                if(checkAlleChbx(i) == true)
                {
                    lehrerGefunden = true;
                    checkAlleChbx(i);
                }
                else
                {
                lehrerGefunden = true;
                if(lehrer.isMehrereklassen() == true && lehrer.isMehrerefaecher() == true)
                {
                    model.addRow(new Object [] {lehrer.getName(), lehrer.getNachname(), lehrer.getKuerzel(), lehrer.getKlasse_1().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getKlasse_2().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getFach().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getFach2().getBezeichnung()});
                }
                else if(lehrer.isMehrereklassen() == true && lehrer.isMehrerefaecher() == false)
                {
                model.addRow(new Object [] {lehrer.getName(), lehrer.getNachname(), lehrer.getKuerzel(), lehrer.getKlasse_1().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getKlasse_2().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getFach().getBezeichnung(), " --- "});
                }
                else if(lehrer.isMehrereklassen() == false && lehrer.isMehrerefaecher() == true)
                {
                model.addRow(new Object [] {lehrer.getName(), lehrer.getNachname(), lehrer.getKuerzel(), lehrer.getKlasse_1().getBezeichnung(), " --- ", lehrer.getFach().getBezeichnung(), lehrer.getFach2().getBezeichnung()});
                }
                else
                {
                model.addRow(new Object [] {lehrer.getName(), lehrer.getNachname(), lehrer.getKuerzel(), lehrer.getKlasse_1().getBezeichnung(), " --- ", lehrer.getFach().getBezeichnung(), " --- "});
                }
                break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!lehrerGefunden)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Die gesuchte Person ist nicht im System!");
            tfSuchfeldLehrer.setText("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Geben Sie einen Namen in das Suchfeld ein!");
    }

}
public boolean checkboxChecking(int i)
{
    model = (DefaultTableModel)table_Lehrer.getModel();
    loescheLehrerTabelle();
            if(chbxKrzelAnzeigen.isSelected())
            {
                chbxKuerzelCheck(i);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
public void chbxKuerzelCheck(int lehrerIndex)
{
    lehrer = lehrerliste.get(lehrerIndex);
    model.addRow(new Object [] {lehrer.getName(), lehrer.getNachname(),lehrer.getKuerzel(), " --- ", " --- ", " --- ", " --- "});
}
public boolean checkAlleChbx(int k)
{
    ChbxGroup();
    System.out.println(chbxListe.get(0).getText());
    model = (DefaultTableModel)table_Lehrer.getModel();
    loescheLehrerTabelle();
    for(int i = 0; i < chbxListe.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(chbxListe.size());
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(chbxListe.get(i).getText());
        model = (DefaultTableModel)table_Lehrer.getModel();
        JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMI = chbxListe.get(i);
        if(cbMI.isSelected())
        {
            String chbxname = cbMI.getText();
            System.out.println(chbxname);
            if(chbxname.equals("K\u00FCrzel Anzeigen"))
            {
                System.out.println("Kürzel gefunden");
                chbxKuerzelCheck(k);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Didn't work!");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False angekommen");
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("True angekommen");
    return true;
}
```

The method `checkBoxChecking` is for individual checking of an checkbox but not used right now.
The method `einzelLehrerSuche()` is the search algorithm linking to the method `checkAlleChbx` where the problem is. I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the code you posted contains the problem. Are you saying it is in this method: `public boolean checkAlleChbx(int k)` ?

Comment: Yes the problem is in this method or at least I think it is, it can also be that the method EinzelLehrerSuche() which refrencess method checkAllChbx() has a problem so that the refrenced method doesnt fire up. But I think its checkAllChbx which contains the problem

Comment: And the problem is that you aren't entering the loop in that method, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < chbxListe.size(); i++)` ?

Comment: But why do I not enter the loop? I wrote the for loop like u mentioned in ur example in the fith row of method checkAllChbx()? Or am I missing something

Comment: It was a question, not a statement. Is the problem that you are not entering the loop? Please answer either "yes" or "no" (if possible).

Comment: I'm either not entering the loop or I am but it doesnt find anything to match with so nothing happens

Comment: *I'm either not entering the loop* - don't guess. Verify what is happening. Add debug code to your loop so see if the loop is executed and display the value of all the variables you are comparing.

Comment: I know now that I enter the loop. I have tested the code of this method now raw in the JMenu MenuListener itself  without calling the method just running the code right at the spot and it worked. This seems very strange to me it should work by just calling the method but it doesnt. Only if typed in directly to the MenuListener it works. Does someone have an explanation for that?